# What causes a potentiometer to get "jittery" after cleaning?

Tags: resistance, potentiometer, jitter, cleaning

I recently cleaned a potentiometer's resistive element by using general purpose contact cleaner (CRC).  I now find that there is "jitter" or non-linear increase in the resistance as I rotate the shaft.  For instance, the resistance might momentarily drop while increasing the resistance, but this only appears to happen if I rotate quickly.

I'm curious what causes this as I suspect I may have damaged the resistive element on the potentiometer.  I cleaned two potentiometers with the same cleaner and the effect is present on both (one worse than the other).

For reference, I am working with Atari Paddle Controllers, which are basically a potentiometer and push button.  The game input and jitter was tolerable prior to cleaning, but now it almost makes the game unusable; the in-game paddle/icon jumps all over the place as the physical potentiometer is rotated.

Comment: Your google profile link appears to be damaged also.

Comment: the pot was probably lubricated, which prevented the slider contact from sticking and "chattering" during motion ... same thing happens when you slide a clean wet finger across a bathroom mirror

Comment: [Grease, it! you cleaned it all off.](https://support.newgatesimms.com/potentiometer-maintenance-and-lubrication-case-study/) (I can't answer why, only how to fix it)

Comment: @jsotola: That makes perfect sense -- I did not consider the vibration of non-lubricated contacts!  Thank you for the suggestion -- will find some dielectric grease and give it a go!

Comment: Some grades of trimpots cannot handle solvents like metalfilm unlike carbon , cermet or WW.

Comment: And the lubrication solved the problem.  Thanks for pointing this out jsotola and @Jeroen3!